# PLACES API_ACCESS NOT CONFIGURED

Tags: android

`status{status code=PLACES API_ACCESS NOT CONFIGURED`,resolution null problem
I used old Google API console and I have also enabled place API, fine access location is properly working.

Comment: Can you provide more information on how to reproduce the error? Also, try to ask a specific question. e.g. I tried running this code, got this error, and I am wondering what is wrong with my code.

Comment: Improved formatting